# Как работает 301 редирект?

Tags: .htaccess

Прописал правило

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/new.php$ $1/new [R=301,L]
```

В соответствии со правилами, первая часть записи указывает участок url, который должен быть заменён записью из второй части. Но такая запись упорно не хочет работать.

Зато работает другая, в которой всё наоборот:

```
RewriteRule ^new$ new.php
```

Исходя из этого, можно сделать вывод, что mod_rewrite работает так: в первой части записывается псевдоним (на него заменяются все реальный ссылки в коде), а во второй ссылка на реальный файл, который доступен по этому псевдониму. Действительно ли всё так работает, или я где-то ошибся? И если всё так, то как сделать редирект на псевдоадрес, когда в строку напрямую вводится настоящее имя файла?

Comment: Для начала приведите пример — редирект откуда куда?

Comment: Внутренний редирект, чтобы при вводе названия реального имени файла, в адресной строке прописывался псевдоним (/new, вместо /new.php). Чтобы к одному файлу была только одна ссылка.

Answer (score 0):

**Пример на основе перевода с http на https:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

**Пример перевода сайта с www на версию без www**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Пример ЧПУ ссылки с 2х символьным языком локализации в начале:**

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})?/?contacts/?$    index.php?lng=$1&module=contacts [L,QSA]
```